# Convert html node to one line string(minify)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dom node in variable and i want to remove all enter/line break, tabs between the html tags. Basically i want to minify it without using external library. How can i do it.

```
var target = document.getElementById('myid');
var wrap = document.createElement('div');
wrap.appendChild(target.cloneNode(true));
```

wrap contains the node..

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23284784/104380

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not elegant, but should work

```
target.innerHTML = target.innerHTML.replace(/\n|\t/g, ' ');
```

Comment: i still see some space.."content_label">                  <h2>

Comment: @shaleen Yes there will be spaces. IMO, it's better than having joined words.

Comment: just in case if i want to remove space between two >   <...how to do it....accepted ur answer..

Comment: `.replace(/> *</g, '><')` would do just that.

Answer (score 4):

You could replace the line breaks with an empty string `target.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");`