# Remove extra spaces only between tags in an HTML string

Tags: javascript, string

Hi I have a HTML string like

```
 "     <div>       <p>You have received an alert from         project <span class='fields'          field='template.variable.ProjectName'>          Project Name</span>        <br />       </p>        <p>        <span          field='template.variable.AlertName'          class='fields'>Alert Name</span> <span          field='template.variable.AlertName'          class='fields'>Alert Name</span> <span          field='template.variable.AlertName'          class='fields'>Alert Name</span>        <br />       </p>        <p>Follow these steps to access the      alert:</p>        <ol>         <li>Log into your  for          Contract Management project         at <span            field='template.variable.AlertProjectLink'            class='fields'>Alert Project Link</span></li>          <li>If necessary, enter your email address and the password          that you created when you completed your         registration.</li>          <li>Go to the Alerts tab to see your          unread alerts and         access links to the documents.</li>      </ol>        <p>        <span class='fields'          field='template.variable.AlertDocumentList'>          Alert Document List</span></p>        <p>Please do not reply        to this message</p>        <p>.Space2 space gaurav Replies are        routed to an unmonitored       mailbox.</p>        <p>If you        would like additional assistance, please contact       Merrill        Technical Support, available 24 hours a day, seven       days a      week.</p>        <p>        <span class='template'          field='template.variable.ImportTemplate'          template='template.types.TechSupportContactInformation'>          Tech Support Contact Information</span> test</p>        <p>Testing is going on</p>     </div>   "
```

I need to replace all the consecutive spaces with single Space but not within tags, Like you can see that I Have

```
`<span field ="template.variable.AlertName"          class="fields">   Alert Name</span>`
```

I need:

```
`<span          field="template.variable.AlertName"          class="fields">Alert Name</span>`
```

As you can see that I don't want to touch spaces of the attributes of HTML tag.

Any help would be highly Appreciated Thanks.

***JAVASCRIPT ONLY**

Comment: use trim() - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp

Comment: @BalajMarius that won't work

Comment: One or more white spaces and line breaks are interpreted as a single white space in HTML, so what's the point?

Comment: FYI, if you remove spaces between pre tag, you will get broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the regex

```
/(<.*?>)|\s+/g
```

with `replace`.

The regex will match

1. `(<.*?>)`: HTML tag and add it in first capturing group(`$1` in replace)
2. `|`: OR in regex
3. `\s+`: Or one or more spaces

In replacement, check if it is HTML tag else, replace extra spaces.

`$1` is first captured group i.e. HTML tag. If tag is present, then don't do anything, else remove the extra spaces.

```js
var html = `     <div>       <p>You have received an alert from         project <span class="fields"          field="template.variable.ProjectName">          Project Name</span>        <br />       </p>        <p>        <span          field="template.variable.AlertName"          class="fields">Alert Name</span> <span          field="template.variable.AlertName"          class="fields">Alert Name</span> <span          field="template.variable.AlertName"          class="fields">Alert Name</span>        <br />       </p>        <p>Follow these steps to access the      alert:</p>        <ol>         <li>Log into your  for          Contract Management project         at <span            field="template.variable.AlertProjectLink"            class="fields">Alert Project Link</span></li>          <li>If necessary, enter your email address and the password          that you created when you completed your         registration.</li>          <li>Go to the Alerts tab to see your          unread alerts and         access links to the documents.</li>      </ol>        <p>        <span class="fields"          field="template.variable.AlertDocumentList">          Alert Document List</span></p>        <p>Please do not reply        to this message</p>        <p>.Space2 space gaurav Replies are        routed to an unmonitored       mailbox.</p>        <p>If you        would like additional assistance, please contact       Merrill        Technical Support, available 24 hours a day, seven       days a      week.</p>        <p>        <span class="template"          field="template.variable.ImportTemplate"          template="template.types.TechSupportContactInformation">          Tech Support Contact Information</span> test</p>        <p>Testing is going on</p>     </div>   `;

var res = html.replace(/(<.*?>)|\s+/g, (m, $1) => $1 ? $1 : ' ');
console.log(res);
```

Comment: It's working fine Thanks for ur answer, But can you please explain this a bit to me

Comment: there are few extra space between tags ` <div> <p>You have`

Comment: @mattn Not few, a single space. That's what OP wants. A single space instead of multiple outside of tags.

Comment: Ah, I understand what OP want now. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I came here also seeking for an answer, but found none helpful, and so came up with another solution which works well for my needs, and wanted to share it with others:

```js
"  <span  class='a  b'> Hello World !  </span>   <p> spaces  </p>   "
.split(/>\s+</) // ["  <span  class='a  b'> Hello World !  </span", 'p> spaces  </p>   ']
.join('><')     // "  <span  class='a  b'> Hello World !  </span><p> spaces  </p>   "
.trim()         // "<span  class='a  b'> Hello World !  </span><p> spaces  </p>"
```

#### Outputs:

```
"<span  class='a  b'> Hello World !  </span><p> spaces  </p>"
```